# IE blocks the execution of some scripts or Activix control

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm developping website .So I downloaded free Bootstrap Template and i integrate it to my web application . This website will be hosted in local in Our company .
When i tested this webapplication in chrome it works well but the problem that most of employees use IE edge , and when i test my application in IE edge (Browser) it displays that (browser blocks the execution of some scripts or Activix control in current page .) So Is there a way to know which scripts or function exactly cause this block .And how can i avoid this message . I'm not interested in changing parameter of browser . I want only to know which function blocks execution and how can i avoid it .

Comment: It's blocking Flash code. Avoid it. I think FF will be blocking it too

Comment: @Justinas . How to find this code .? In Js files ?

Comment: You should better know where are you using Flash instead of JS.